# Reliable and accurate threading structure for emails?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, email

I'm working on a email project. I would like to display email in threads just like gmail.

What is the best approach to display mails in thread?

I have checked [jwz threading algorithm](https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html).  But looks like that algorithm is written for projects that has no databases.That algorithm focuses on these three header keys. `Message-ID`, `In-Reply-To` and `References`

Can someone tell me what is the proper, efficient and most accurate way to achieve threading using mysql database.?

Do I have to use separate table for threads and references?

If possible give me some sample mysql queries. So I can understand better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any message board design eg wordpress etc should also works for email. I also come up with a design:

```
email.id user_id subject status  folder created updated ...other info you'd save
1        123     Hello   New     Inbox  Y-m-d.. Y-m-d.. ...
2        3456    World   Replied Inbox  ...

reply.id email_id reply_to_id user_id created email_txt ip ...
10       1        0           890     Y-m-d.. Hi ...
20       2        0           5678    ...
30       2        20          3456    ...     Replyto 2
55       2        30          5678    ....    Replyto 3
```

So in your email.folder.index page:

```
SELECT * FROM email WHERE user_id = 12345 ORDER BY updated desc LIMIT 50
```

And when you click one an email on index page, goto email details page:

```
SELECT * FROM reply WHERE email_id = 2 ORDER BY created, reply_to_id
```

The key magic is that the tree is built based on reply_to_id